# How to find all non trivial subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If $b\in <S_{6},\bullet>$ , $b= \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1&2&3&4&5&6\\
      2&3&4&5&6&1
    \end{array}
\right] $

and the subgroup

$H=<b>= $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
b= \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1&2&3&4&5&6\\
      2&3&4&5&6&1
    \end{array}
\right] ,b^{2}= \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1&2&3&4&5&6\\
      3&4&5&6&1&2
    \end{array}
\right]\\b^{3}= \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1&2&3&4&5&6\\
      4&5&6&1&2&3
    \end{array}
\right] ,b^{4}= \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1&2&3&4&5&6\\
      5&6&1&2&3&4
    \end{array}
\right]\\ 
b^{5}= \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1&2&3&4&5&6\\
      6&1&2&3&4&5
    \end{array}
\right],b^{6}= \left[
 \begin{array}{cc}
      1&2&3&4&5&6\\
      1&2&3&4&5&6
    \end{array}
\right]=e\\\end{array}\
\right\}$

I need to find all non trivial subgroup of $H$.

Using Lagrange's theorem and the fact that any subgroup of $H$ (mark them $K_i$) is non trivial if: $$\{e\}\subset K_{i}$$ and $$K_{i}\neq\{e\},K_{i}\neq\ H$$
that means  $o(K_{i})\neq 1,o(K_{i})\neq 6$

so it must be that $o(K_{i})=2$ or $o(K_{i})=3$

if $o(K_{i})=2$,then I found one subgroup:$K_{1}=\{b^{6}=e,b^{3}\}$

if $o(K_{i})=3$,then I found one subgroup:$K_{2}=\{b^{6}=e,b^{2},b^{4}\}$

How can I find more?

Is there any fast way to find them all?

Thanks.

Comment: You found all (both) of them.

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: Note that $H$ is cyclic, so its subgroups are cyclic as well.

Comment: So the subgroups must have a generator. $<b>$ is the generator of $H$ so it can't be a generator of another subgroup.

 $<b3>$ is the generator of $K1$ so it can't be a generator of another subgroup.

 $<b2>$ is the generator of $K2$ so it can't be a generator of another subgroup. 
$\require{cancel}$
I left with $b4$, $b5$,because $4\cancel{|}6$,$5\cancel{|}6$
 it can't be a generator ? – Asaf 5 mins ago

Comment: @5xum can you explain?

Comment: @Asaf Sorry I was away. Well, $b^4$ can be a generator, but it will simply generate the same group as $b^2$. And $b^5$ will generate the entire $H$, just like $b$. And, naturally, $b^0$ generates the trivial group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$o(H)=6$,$H$ is cylic,so $\phi(6)=2$.

$H$ has 2 generators. $<b>$ is a generator,so:  $o(b)=6$ and
$$o(b^{t})=\frac{o(b)}{gcd(o(b),t)}=\frac{6}{gcd(6,t)}$$
to find the second generator:$o(b^{t})=6$ this happens iff $gcd(6,t)=1$

so,$t=1$ and $t=5$ means that $<b^{5}>=H$

There is only 2 non trivial subgroups.